# Image animation when it's loaded

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have the listbox with Image control and with binding source.

What i want: when image is loaded (i think it's ImageOpened event?), animate opacity property from 0 to 100. Som apps, like Facebook, use this effect.

Image control is inside DataTemplate and there are a lot of listbox items.

How to solve?

P.S. I tried to create Trigger for Image control that changes opacity property after ImageOpened event, but app crushed without any showed causes in debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may initially set the Image `Opacity` to zero and attach an `ImageOpened` handler that animates the `Opacity` to one.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Image Source="{Binding}" Opacity="0" ImageOpened="OnImageOpened"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

The `ImageOpened` handler:

```
private void OnImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var opacityAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        To = 1,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
    };

    Storyboard.SetTarget(opacityAnimation, (DependencyObject)sender);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(opacityAnimation,
                                 new PropertyPath(Image.OpacityProperty));

    var storyboard = new Storyboard();
    storyboard.Children.Add(opacityAnimation);
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did the same first time, but i made a mistake in SetTargetProperty and i had NullRefException there. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

DataTemplate :

```
<DataTemplate>
<Image Source="{Binding}" Opacity="0" ImageOpened="image_ImageOpened"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Image animation :

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="image">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="1"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

ImageOpened handler :

```
 private void image_ImageOpened(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     Storyboard1.Begin();
 }
```